# Find missing numbers in list of file names in one query

Tags: sql-server, numbers, sequence

In document management database there is a list of existing files. New files are supposed to get a number, such as **SW_01234.xxx**. There is a numbering mechanism that serves the new numbers. Question is to find the missing elements - for example if file was deleted.

Existing file names might be completely different and not following the scheme above.

My attempt was to do it this way :

1. Split existing files at the "dot" - I don't care about .xxx extension, like .doc, .xlsx
2. Generate a temporary list of SW_00000 to SW_99999
3. Bring those element that exist in b) but not a)

Sample values

```
..  
SW_00015.PRT  
SW_00016.DRW  
SW_00020.DRW  
SW_00020.PDF  
XBC115.DOC  
..
```

I need to get SW_00017, SW_00018, SW_00019 (don't care about the XBC)

Need to have one query in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you 99% of the way there.  Tweak as necessary.  You'll notice that records, 1, 3, 4, and 10 are all missing from the output.

```
DECLARE @allFiles TABLE (Name VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @dataset TABLE (name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dataset
        ( name )
VALUES  ( 'SW_00001.PRT'), ('SW_00003.DRW'), ('SW_00004.DRW'), ('SW_00010.PDF'
          );

WHILE @i < 100
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @allFiles
            ( Name )
    VALUES  ( 'SW_' +  REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(@i)) + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10))  -- Name - varchar(100)
              );

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

SELECT *
FROM @allFiles af
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @dataset ds WHERE af.Name = SUBSTRING(ds.name, 0, CHARINDEX('.', ds.name)))
```

Comment: This one did immediately what I was looking for! Thx. I only had to replace the INSERT with INSERT from Table xx - and there was another one: I had to extend the VARCHAR(100) to 200 - as there are filenames with 150 characters  ;-)  Thx

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement your approach all in one query. In order to do it all in one query, I used CTEs to isolate the document numbers and also to get the range of numbers to use in the "not exists" part. If you need more range in the numbers table, you can get the range by querying differently. See [Generate Sequential Set of Numbers](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

```
declare @t as table (DocName varchar(50));

insert @t (DocName)
values 
('SW_00015.PRT')
,('SW_00016.DRW')
,('SW_00020.DRW')
,('SW_00020.PDF');


/*doing with CTE so the split and substring is more readable, plus needed it anyway for getting the numbers table*/
with isolatedFileNames
as (
    /*might be dots in filename, reversing it to isolate the last set (file ext)*/
    select DocName
        ,left(DocName, len(DocName) - charindex('.', reverse(DocName), 0)) as IsolatedDocName 
    from @t
    )
    ,isolatedNumbers
as (
    /*substring to get the number without the prefix*/
    select DocName
        ,IsolatedDocName
        ,cast(substring(IsolatedDocName, charindex('_', IsolatedDocName, 0) + 1, len(IsolatedDocName)) as int) as IsolatedDocNumber
    from isolatedFileNames
    )
    ,numbers
as (
    /*use row_number on a large set to get the range*/
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (
            order by object_id
            ) + (
            /*start at the first document number, change this to 0 if you want to start at 0*/
            select min(IsolatedDocNumber) - 1
            from isolatedNumbers
            ) as num
    from sys.all_objects
    )
    ,numbersLessThanDocNumbers
as (
    select num
    from numbers
    where num < (
            /*limit to max document number in the set*/
            select max(IsolatedDocNumber)
            from isolatedNumbers
            )
    )
select num as MissingFromDocumentSet
from numbersLessThanDocNumbers n
where not exists (
        select 1
        from isolatedNumbers iso
        where iso.IsolatedDocNumber = n.num
        )
```

Comment: Even though this one look good readable I did not manage to get it going. However i like this as it feels like VB.net (that I am familiar with)

Comment: Did you get an error message or did it just not return results? I ran this myself in SSMS before posting, perhaps I edited it in some way that broke it, I'll check when I get back in front of my dev machine.

Comment: So when I run this in SSMS, I get a set of numbers showing the missing values in the series: 17, 18, 19. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Hi, I just let go another time. Indeed there is no error message. Might be that I was confused a Little as the result are purged and only give core number (17, 18) not the whole number (SW_00017).  Indeed this Looks pretty interessting for me as I Need to extend this script soon.  Thx. thx.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that part about the whole file name. If the results are always SW_12345 you could simply concatenate to the front of the num field in that last part of the query. I guess you'd have to pad the num to the left with zeros though.